# How to optimize a Tensorflow model for Serving

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

I trained a model with Keras. Now I want to deploy it via Tensorflow serving. Therefore, I converted it to the SavedModel format in that way:

```
K.set_learning_phase(0)
    K._LEARNING_PHASE = tf.constant(0)
    # sess = K.get_session()
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    export_path = os.path.join(
        tf.compat.as_bytes(path),
        tf.compat.as_bytes(str(get_new_version(path=path, current_version=int(version)))))
    print('Learning phase', K.learning_phase())
    print('Exporting trained model to', export_path)
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

    model_input = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.input)
    model_output = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.output)

    prediction_signature = (
        tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs={'inputs': model_input},
            outputs={'output': model_output},
            method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

    with K.get_session() as sess:

        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess=sess, tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
            signature_def_map={
                'predict':
                    prediction_signature,
            })

        builder.save()
```

I started using by Tensorflow serving (installed Tensorflow-model-server via apt-get install). But my model is 376 MB in size (both saved_model.pb and variables folder) and prediction time is very high (about 0.3 second per request) and when rps increases the latency decreases.

So, I want to optimize my model, does anybody know some tricks to do it?

P.S. My model in Keras is saved with `save_model(model)`.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

1. Be sure you didn't leave any queues (e.g. FIFOQueue) in your serving model. Those are often used in training to hide I/O latencies, but can hurt serving performance.
2. Consider enabling batching multiple inference requests together into a single call to the TF model/graph. See --enable_batching, with tuning via --batching_parameters_file.
3. Other than those tips, you'll have to look into the structure of your model itself. Perhaps others have insights on that.

-Chris (TF-Serving team)

Comment: Thank you for answer, Chris, could you tell about FIFIQueue in model?

Comment: And am I right, that when I do saving model, the graph freeze?

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your model with [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware but it should work with any CPU. It automatically optimizes your model by converting to Intermediate Representation (IR), performing graph pruning and fusing some operations into others while preserving accuracy. Then it uses vectorization in runtime.

There is even [OpenVINO Model Server](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/model_server) which behaves very similarly to Tensorflow Serving.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Keras model to OpenVINO unless you have fancy custom layers. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, which is a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (just change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --input_shape "[1, 3, 224, 224]" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what is the best choice for you, just use AUTO.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="CPU")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.